# Getting error while compiling Freertos library in Spark fun Arduino Pro Micro

Tags: arduino, atmega

Im Using latest arduino nightly build v 1.6.10 to compile sample program for Arduino Pro Micro Which uses ATmega32U4. I just downloaded FreeRtos Library from Library Manager. Using very simple empty sketch to compile using #include

but im getting following errror while compiling:

```
C:\Users\Rajendra\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FreeRTOS\src\variantHooks.c: In function 'initVariant':

C:\Users\Rajendra\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FreeRTOS\src\variantHooks.c:88:2: error: 'USBDevice' undeclared (first use in this function)

  USBDevice.attach();

  ^

C:\Users\Rajendra\Documents\Arduino\libraries\FreeRTOS\src\variantHooks.c:88:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

exit status 1
Error compiling for board SparkFun Pro Micro.
```

what is the possibility for getting this error?

Comment: Post your code please. For the last error, you are probably redefining one of the hooks, probably vApplicationIdleHook. But you should post your could for us to see.

Comment: @Ouss4 as i said sketch is empty, with empty setup and loop block. The issue is with library ... I'm not getting. I guess some one who has compiled it successfully might be able to know about this. The library i used here is from Arduino Library manager (by Richard Berry)
Meanwhile I tried another one which is working for few sketches nicely 
https://github.com/greiman/FreeRTOS-Arduino

Comment: I do use the Richard Berry one with no problems with Arduino Mega.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was raised as [Issue #22](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library/issues/22) on my FreeRTOS library, in July 2017.

Best resolved by ensuring that the [latest version of the Library](https://github.com/feilipu/Arduino_FreeRTOS_Library) is installed.